# Why is the parachutist, in the enclosed image, not electrocuted?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, voltage

Hello fellow physics experts,

In reference to a recent electrodynamics course a question about electric potential difference was asked. This question states why the dangling parachutist in de picture below is not electrocuted by the power lines. A possible explanation could be that the parachutist is the unintented 'connection' between the two cables that have a potential difference of 0V across them, therefore the electric field between those two cables is zero, which means no current will flow through the parachutist. Of course I am not sure whether this explanation is physically correct, and I would appreciate a correction, when applicable.
[image]

Comment: Are parachute cords conductive? If not, why do you think the parachutist is connected to both cables? (Or is there something in the image I'm missing?)

Comment: Well according to my physics book the parachutist is not electrocuted, but the explanation is omitted, because the image belongs to the start of the chapter. Furthermore, looking at the picture, the parachutist holds the lower cable with his hands and the cords are in connection with the upper cable. As to whether the parachute cords are conductive of not seems irrelevant, since the resistance compared the potential difference would be negligible. Perhaps I'm wrong, nonetheless, I look forward to your view.

Comment: Well, I suppose if the potential difference were so high perhaps this would be the case. I am not sure of the numbers, so I can't be certain. Nevertheless, it would certainly matter if the connecting object is conductive or not! If the wires were made of wood (as an extreme example) and 1 metre long, their resistance would be of the order of $10^{14}\Omega$, which is a *lot*! If the potential difference could overcome that, it could come close to overcoming the air in between the two wires, and wouldn't need to use the parachutist to get current flowing :)

Comment: Another question you might find interesting [Why does energy flow between a high voltage transmission line and linemen approaching it on a helicopter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234175/157014).